# ¿Cómo puedo darle un valor al (name="$valor") del input, ya que no quiero que el usuario escriba en la caja sino que al dar enviar se envíe mi $valor?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
    
    $c = 'VALOR OTORGADO POR MI'; ?>
    
    <form action="php.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name='<?php $c ?>'>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Mi problema es que quiero darle un valor al name del input y que este se envíe por POST a otro archivo en el cual se imprimirá ese valor.

```
    <?php 
        
        $e = $_POST["$c"];
        echo "$e";
     ?>
```

El anterior código es el segundo archivo y es donde quiero que se imprima el valor que se envió desde el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias realizar lo siguiente:

1. Agregar otro input escondido con un name conocido, como por ejemplo, `valor_name`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="valor_name" value="<?php echo $c; ?>">
```

2. Y en el otro archivo recuperarlo con:

```
$e = $_POST["valor_name"];
```

3. Modificar tu primer input así:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $c; ?>" value="<?php echo $valor_c; ?>">
```

suponiendo que ese name tiene un valor (que he bautizado como `$valor_c`), sino no tendria sentido usar un input para enviar tan solo un `name` sin valor.

4. Y finalmente podrias recoger ese valor_c en el PHP con esto:

```
$valor_e = $_POST[$e];
```

teniendo en cuenta que **antes** has hecho los otros pasos previos para definir lo que es $e.

---

Otra forma seria dejarlo tal cual lo tienes y en el PHP imprimir todo el $_POST para ver lo que contiene, así:

```
foreach($_POST as $clave=>$valor) {
  echo "La clave ".$clave." contiene este valor:".$valor."<br>";
}
```

Ya nos dirás si te sirve.